# convert tradingview script into python3

Tags: python

I am looking for a converting from TV to python. Just a little code. This is the code in tradingview :

```
last_signal = 0
long_final = longCond and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == -1)
short_final = shortCond and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == 1)

last_signal := long_final ? 1 : short_final ? -1 : last_signal[1]
```

for variable :
-> longCond and shortCond, i have the right value (I compared between plot)

But for others, i have some differences (i think, because of last_signal)

this is my code in python :

```
  for x in range(0,len(mavi),1):
    last_signal[i] = 0
    if x == 0:
      longCond_tmp = 0
      shortCond_tmp  = 0
      last_signal_tmp  = 0
      short_final_tmp  = 0
      long_final_tmp  = 0

    else:
      if ((longCond_tmp and ((last_signal[i-1])) == 0) or ((last_signal[i-1]) == -1)):
        long_final_tmp = 1
      else:
        long_final_tmp = 0

      if ((shortCond_tmp and ((last_signal[i-1])) == 0) or ((last_signal[i-1]) == 1)):
        short_final_tmp = 1
      else:
        short_final_tmp = 0

      if long_final_tmp != 0:
        last_signal_tmp = 1
      else:
        if short_final_tmp != 0:
          last_signal_tmp = -1
        else:
          last_signal_tmp = last_signal[i-1]

    last_signal[i] += last_signal_tmp
```

Are there errors in my script in python ?

Comment: _Are there errors_... Use an IDE and it'll tell you that itself

Comment: no you don't understand, my script works but results are a bit different from results of trading view

Comment: I see, well, `long_final ? 1 : short_final`, for example, isn't python code and it's hard to say what the `nz()` function does for a valid comparison

Comment: hm for nz() : "we use the nz() function so that any NaN value is replaced with a 0 (TradingView, n.d.) "

Comment: Thanks for that. Now, is it possible to give the value of `mavi` variable? It's not clear how that maps to the given tradingview code. Also what is `i` vs `x` in your Python?

Comment: mavi is just an other variable but it is correct (assume that longCond_tmp  and shortCond_tmp  are correct)
i want to know if the calculation of last_signal_tmp and last_signal is equivalent with tradingview script ?

Comment: Seems okay to me, but `i` is never defined

Comment: i = 0 before the iteration "for" and at the end of the iteration
i += 1

Comment: If that's the case, seems like using x would make more sense. It should be equal

Comment: yes, you're right, an idea for the other issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found.
Just the number of "(" in

```
      if ((longCond_tmp and ((last_signal[i-1])) == 0) or ((last_signal[i-1]) == -1)):
    long_final_tmp = 1
  else:
    long_final_tmp = 0

  if ((shortCond_tmp and ((last_signal[i-1])) == 0) or ((last_signal[i-1]) == 1)):
    short_final_tmp = 1
  else:
    short_final_tmp = 0
```